# Error by using changes (\listofchanges) with documentclass amsart

Tags: amsart, changes, ifthenelse, xifthen

I want to use the package `changes` with the document class `amsart`, however, I get the following error message:

> ```
> ! Undefined control sequence.
> <argument> \equal 
>                  {\Changes@loc@style }{list}
> ```

The following code produces the error and if one changes `amsart` to `scrartcl` it would work. (it also works if one would not use `\listofchanges`)

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage[draft]{changes}
\definechangesauthor[color=orange]{JFK}

\begin{document}

test \added[id=JFK,comment=test2]{test comment}
\listofchanges

\end{document}
```

Is there any solution or it is not possible to use this package with the `amsart` document class?

Thank you for any help.

**EDIT:** 
I took the error message summarized by TeXstudio. Now, I took the actual error message out of the log file.

**EDIT:**
The problem seems not to be between `amsart` and `changes`, since the user daleif posted a MWE which throws the same error

```
\documentclass{amsart}
%\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xifthen}% used by changes.sty
\def\test{test}
\begin{document}
\section*{
   \ifthenelse{\equal{\test}{test}}{it says test}{nope}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Since `\ifthenelse` is special, I'm not sure if it is a bug of `amsart` that you can't use it in `\section*`. But regardless of that I suggest you notify the maintainer of `changes` and suggest to him to slightly invert the order of `\section*` and `\ifthenelse` in his code. Instead of `\section*{...\ifthenelse...}` it would probably be safer to only call `\section*` when `\ifthenelse` has done its work.

Comment: I reported this issue https://gitlab.com/ekleinod/changes/issues/55

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the new version of `changes` 3.1.2, the problem is fixed. For more information see

https://gitlab.com/ekleinod/changes/issues/55